# Rails before_filter check multiple roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, roles, before-filter

In my before filter, I call a method containing the following code:

```
authorized_for_roles :administrator
```

In my `application_controller`

```
def authorized_for_roles(*roles)
roles.each{|role_name| return true if current_user.role.name == role_name}
```

This does not seem to be returning true even when logged in with the administrator role.  Is my syntax incorrect?

If I switch the code to just read

```
return true if current_user.is_an_administrator?
```

everything works great.  Can someone tell me how to modify the code to check is_an? for each role passed to the method?  I'd like to be able to do something like

```
authorized_for_roles :administrator, :moderator
```

I tried

```
roles.each{|role_name|return true if current_user.try(:is_an, role_name)}
```

but this did not work.

EDIT: changed line spacing so that code snippets are formatted as such...

Comment: Are you using a gem for roles ? What is the is_an_administrator? definition ?

Comment: I got it from Ernie Miller - [link]http://metautonomo.us/2008/09/30/easy-role-based-authorization/ `code` def method_missing(method_id, *args) if match = matches_dynamic_role_check?(method_id) tokenize_roles(match.captures.first).each do |check| return true if role.name.downcase == check end return false else super end end private def matches_dynamic_role_check?(method_id) /^is_an?_([a-zA-Z]\w*)\?$/.match(method_id.to_s) end def tokenize_roles(string_to_split) string_to_split.split(/_or_/) end

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the Enumerable#any? method. In your first example:

```
def authorized_for_roles (*roles)
  roles.any? { |role_name| current_user.role.name == role_name }
end
```